# multiple Inputtext fields update a commandbutton

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm new in programming with jsf and i want to hear your informed opinion.
I have the following problem. I have 4 input text fields (could be also an primeface one) in jsf, which should update a primeface command button. If one of the four fields not valid then the command button should be disabled. In my example has the button his own disable-function in the controller. One solution is over the ajax event "keyup" to trigger the controller for an update, but is this the best solution? The disable-function from the command button is called quit often.

```
<p:commandButton value="Name" id="saveButton" styleClass="xxx"
                 action="#{controller.saveEntity}"
                 disabled="#{controller.disableButton}"
                 rendered="#{controller.editmode}" update="msg" />

<h:inputText id="firstname" value="#{controller.user.firstName}"
                            rendered="#{controller.editmode}" >
        <f:ajax event="keyup" delay="200" render="saveButton" />
</h:inputText>
```

the other input fields are the same structure.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137919/multiple-inputtext-fields-update-a-commandbutton help?